# density plots for psm balance diagnostics

Tags: r, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to make a series of nice density plots to show balance for variables in a psm analysis.

```
full_match <- matchit(buyout_flag ~ tsale + sfincs_avg + logprox + tenure + age +
                     percent_ethwhite_origin + percent_poverty_origin + percent_hs_origin + percent_owner_origin + house_medval_origin + percap_origin,
                   method = "full", distance = "glm", link = "probit", data = hcad_floodp, caliper = 0.1)
```

The basic plot function produces a simple series of them (over three+ plots).

```
plot(full_match, type = "density")
```

[image]

The cobalt:bal.plot produces nicer plots, but I can only figure out how to do one at a time. Can I make a series or grid of plots for all variables using bal.plot?

```
bal.plot(full_match, var.name = "distance", which = "both")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do more than one variable at a time using `bal.plot()`, but you can use something like `patchwork` to combine multiple plots into one. See below for an example.

```r
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")
library(cobalt); library(MatchIt)
library(patchwork)

m <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
               nodegree + re74 + re75, data = lalonde,
             method = "full", link = "probit")

bal.plot(m, "age", which = "both") /
  bal.plot(m, "educ", which = "both") /
  bal.plot(m, "re74", which = "both") +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

```r
bal.plot(m, "nodegree", which = "both") /
  bal.plot(m, "race", which = "both") /
  bal.plot(m, "married", which = "both") +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The plots above don't look great because of the sizing but you can change your graphics device size to make it look nicer. The categorical and continuous covariates need to be plotted separately for the legends to be gathered correctly. With some additional programming, you can really customize the plots to look prettier, e.g., by removing the title from each plot using `ggplot2::labs()`, removing the legend using `ggplot2::guides(fill = "none")`, etc.